# Can't fadeOut specific element within array

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, fadeout

I'm sure this is really easy and I'm just not understanding it. But I'm trying to target the first element of a jquery selector and fadeOut that element. I can fade both elements, but can't fade either one individually using the indices. I keep getting a "jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...)[0].fadeOut is not a function" error. I'm using codepen so the jquery library and SCSS are loaded into it.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/371633/pexels-photo-371633.jpeg" class="container__image">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/414171/pexels-photo-414171.jpeg" class="container__image">
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

.container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 15px auto;

  &__image {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  } 
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container__image")[0].fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `eq` .

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".container__image").eq(0).fadeOut();
 });
```

Or you can use `array` like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var array = [];
  $('.container__image').each(function(i, li) {
    array.push($(li));
  });
  array[0].fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. The first option worked like I hoped. Is there a reason I can't just call [0] on $(".container__image")? Thanks again!

Comment: You have to store  `container__image` in an array first then you can call like u said.